# codeless kext on OS X

Tags: xcode, iokit, darwin, kernel-extension

Ok i am working on a uController project (pointer device), i am trying to write a user space driver `IOkit.framework`.

using the idProduct and idVendor i can get the `IOUSBInterfaceInterface300` obj

the problem is when i try

> `kr = (*intf)->USBInterfaceOpen(intf);`

it fails with `kIOReturnExclusiveAccess`, most likely because the `HID` manager has opened the device already with exclusive access.

Here it says that a codeless kext can prevent the HID manager from taking over the device

[Reading and writing to USB (HID) interrupt endpoints on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368008/reading-and-writing-to-usb-hid-interrupt-endpoints-on-mac)

I created a kext with the `idVendor` and `idProduct` and used kextload to load it.
i get back **"loaded successfully"** from kextload

but somehow i still cant open the interface?
am i doing something wrong?

I created the kext by creating a file name Info.plist (the content identical to that post with the idProduct and idVendor adjusted) and put it in a folder named MyUSBDeviceTest.kext

then change the owner to root:wheel
then copy the kext to `/System/Library/Extensions` then

```
sudo kextload -vt /System/Library/Extensions/MyUSBDeviceTest.kext
```

i've tried restarting and reconnecting the device but i just cant take the interface from the `HID` system

Comment: Loading a codeless kext doesn't really make any sense. You need to place it in SLE (with appropriate permissions) and connect the device (or reboot). If that doesn't work, the matching rules for your IOKitPersonality aren't right. Post those and the ioreg properties of the HID object that actually succeeds in matching if you need some help.

Comment: never mind i found another way to do it with HID Manager, but thanks

Comment: Consider answering your own question with the HID manager solution, so the next person with the problem can use it too!